# How to schedule a Snowflake Dashboard share over the email

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The ask is to share the Resource Monitor/ Credit Utilization dashboard among the team everyday over the email. How can we schedule it?

Comment: The dashboard only exists in Snowflake so I'm not sure what you mean by sharing it. You can send the link to people but there's no point doing this everyday as the link doesn't change. Sharing dashboards is documented here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-dashboards.html#sharing-dashboards

Comment: To clarify your concern, currently I download Resource Monitor Dashboard and send it across the team as an email attachment. I would like to automate this activity. Thanks!

Comment: You definitely can't do this using just Snowflake functionality. There may be a tool out there that could script it but I doubt it - though someone may know better than me

Comment: Thanks for your reply @NickW. I came across a forum saying Tableau or QliqView can be used for generating similar dashboard and publishing across the mail recipients. I hope that will suffice the need. Thanks!

Comment: For that matter any BI product can be leveraged to build out dashboards from the data aggregated from multiple sources per business requirement.